# Включить и выключить TextBox с помощью кнопки Button c#

Tags: c#, button, textbox

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы при нажатии на Button один раз TextBox включился и второй раз нажать на этот же Button TextBox должен выключится. Спасибо.

Comment: просто в обработчик клика добавить что-то такое : `textBox.Enabled = !textBox.Enabled;`

Comment: WPF или WinForms?

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!! Получилось.

Comment: Уважаемые пользователи. Если вы получили ответ на свой вопрос, просьба не забывать помечать его как ответ! Это важно!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно создать `Togglie Button`, с флагом отвечающим за нажатие.
Вот небольшое [**видео**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U9-4Gk-3Y40) на эту тему.
В данном видео автор изменяет цвет `picture box`, а вы можете управлять свойством `TextBox` -  `textBox.Enabled = false;` либо `textBox.readOnly = true;`

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!! Получилось.

Comment: @Евгений в таком случае отметте мой ответ как решение. ;)

Comment: внешние ссылки имеют свойство умирать время от времени. Вы могли бы разместить в ответе самое необходимое с минимальными пояснениями, а ссылку оставить как указание на источник.